# How does dynamic Roles in BPM Metastorm works?

Tags: business-process-management

I have instruction of this tool, but I can't find anything specyfic.
I'm trying to hide some form for specyfic folders. To do so I defined a role with formula:

```
SelectSql(null,"SELECT Id FROM MyDb WHERE EFolderId != '" + ProcessContext.FolderId + "'")
```

Than, in forms property, I inserted my new role to "Restricted viewing to...". That deed stopped form from being viewd at all!
What can I do to make it properly?
What is the usage of formulas during creating roles?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Formulas are way to select user names. Quasi query to formula looks kile this:

```
SelectSql(null,"SELECT TOP 1 '" + ProcessContext.UserName + "' FROM...).Text
```